# Unknown option when running mix release

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've just upgraded Elixir from 1.7.4 to 1.10.4 on my build server and I'm getting this error:

```
** (Mix) Could not invoke task "release": 2 errors found!
--env : Unknown option
--no-tar : Unknown option
```

The command remained the same as before, which is:

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix release --env=prod --no-tar
```

When I try to run without these two flags the build works but I can't get the server running. These are the errors.

```
{"could not start kernel pid",application_controller,"error in config file \"/mokily/gerard/releases/222.38.10/sys.config\" (none): configuration file not found"}

could not start kernel pid (application_controller) (error in config file "/mokily/gerard/releases/222.38.10/sys.config" (none): configuration file not found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. These flags are not needed for release. `env` is already specified by `MIX_ENV=prod`, `tar` won’t be built.
2. Before issuing [`mix release`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.10.4/Mix.Tasks.Release.html) one must prepare the source tree to release with [`mix release.init`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.10.4/Mix.Tasks.Release.Init.html#content).

Comment: Tried to do so, but faced the same problem:
releases/24.38.10/sys.config" (none): configuration file not found)

Comment: How do you start your release?

Comment: I just found out that there was a script being executed after my build script that was moving the sys.config file from the right place (totally my bad). So it couldn't be found because it actually didn't exist. And I take the opportunity to add that the mix release.init was really missing in my build script. So thanks for the help